# C# add a new calendar

Tags: ios, xamarin, calendar

I would like to know how to add a new native calendar into the app of ios through the method viewdidload and save it. i've already tried to convert this code to c# but didnt work. Thanks

```
EKEventStore* eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
NSString* calendarName = @"My Cal";
EKCalendar* calendar;

// Get the calendar source
EKSource* localSource;
for (EKSource* source in eventStore.sources) {
if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
{
    localSource = source;
    break;
}
}

if (!localSource)
return;

calendar = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:eventStore];
calendar.source = localSource;
calendar.title = calendarName;

NSError* error;
bool success= [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
NSLog(error.description);
// TODO: error handling here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation seems pretty straightforward, but you do need to ask permission to access the Calendar. First, you need to add the following to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app will use your calendar for ...</string>
```

So either use a text editor to add the above in the root `<dict>` element, or open the Info.plist in Xamarin Studio and select the `Source` tab and add a new Entry choosing `Privacy - Calendars Usage Description` with a type of `String` and the enter the text in the `Value` field that the permission alert will show the user.

Then in your app, you need to actually request permission with:

```
EKEventStore eventStore = new EKEventStore();
eventStore.RequestAccess(EKEntityType.Event, (granted, calerror) => {});
```

Complete working code in a ViewDidLoad method:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        EKEventStore eventStore = new EKEventStore();
        eventStore.RequestAccess(EKEntityType.Event, (granted, calerror) => 
        {
            if (granted)
            {
                string calendarName = "My Cal";
                EKCalendar calendar = EKCalendar.FromEventStore(eventStore);
                calendar.Title = calendarName;


                EKSource localSource = null;
                foreach (EKSource source in eventStore.Sources)
                {
                    if (source.SourceType == EKSourceType.Local)
                    {
                        localSource = source;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (localSource == null)
                    return;


                calendar.Source = localSource;

                NSError error = null;
                bool success = eventStore.SaveCalendar(calendar, true, out error);
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Description);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Permission Denied");

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it compiles fine on the ipad but im still trying to add the calendar to the app, do you know if i have to add a key in the info.plist? Thanks again

Comment: sorry, i meant if i have to add something else in the code to add the calendar in the iOS native calendar app

Comment: I tested the above code and it did add the calendar "My Cal" to the iOS native calendar app. The entry you need in the Info.plist is also in my answer above.

Comment: Let me add that if you have previously run the app and not given permission to the Calendar then that permission denial will already be set and you will not be asked for permission again. Either go to settings and enable Calendar permission for your app, or uninstall the app and reinstall once you have the above code in your app project.

Comment: Sure!, also i have another question to ask: everytime that the viewdidload executes i need to check if the calendar is available if its true it needs to be remove and then created again and if its false it just have to be created . It have to be this way because after this i need to make a synch with all the events from the calendars. How can i check that?